# Bundler caching on Travis CI with multiple gemfiles

Tags: bundler, travis-ci

The new docker-based [build environment](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/workers/container-based-infrastructure/) supports bundler caching on open source projects.

I'm trying to enable it in a [pull request](https://github.com/GetJobber/recurring_select/pull/75) but it fails.

I don't know if it can be used when using a build matrix with multiple Gemfiles:

```
gemfile:
   - spec/gemfiles/Gemfile.rails-3.2.x
   - spec/gemfiles/Gemfile.rails-4.0.x
   - spec/gemfiles/Gemfile.rails-4.1.x
   - spec/gemfiles/Gemfile.rails-4.2.x
```

Has anyone got this working and can share their `.travis.yml`?

Comment: I'm unable to make caching work as well.. (bundler/ruby). I wonder if that's just a problem of documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arbitrary directories can be cached.

> **Arbitrary directores**
>
> You can cache arbitrary directories, such as Gradle, Maven, Composer and npm cache directories, between builds by listing them in your .travis.yml:
>
> ```
> cache:
>   directories:
>   - .autoconf
>   - $HOME/.m2
> ```
>
> — [Travis CI Documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/caching/)

I don't know where gemfiles are cached, but say it's `~/.gem/specs`:

```
 cache:
   directories:
   - $HOME/.gem/specs
```

The Travis CI build log will print something along the lines of:

```
Setting up build cache

$ export CASHER_DIR=$HOME/.casher

$ Installing caching utilities                        0.05s
                                                      0.00s
attempting to download cache archive                  0.47s
fetching master/cache-linux-precise-xxx-xxx-xxx.tgz
found cache
                                                      0.00s
adding /home/travis/.gem/specs                        1.28s
```